# Error while using Matlab System commnad

Tags: matlab

i am extracting dense video feature. The problem i am facing is that when i run in linux terminal.

```
./release/DenseTrackStab /home/shashank/Documents/MATLAB/stip_fisher-master/UCF50/BaseballPitch/v_BaseballPitch_g08_c07.avi | tee > /home/shashank/Documents/MATLAB/stip_fisher-master/data/ucf-50/BaseballPitch/v_BaseballPitch_g08_c07.stip
```

it works perfectly fine .

when i do same in matlab using system command

```
>> system('./release/DenseTrackStab /home/shashank/Documents/MATLAB/stip_fisher-master/UCF50/BaseballPitch/v_BaseballPitch_g08_c07.avi | tee > /home/shashank/Documents/MATLAB/stip_fisher-master/data/ucf-50/BaseballPitch/v_BaseballPitch_g08_c07.stip')
```

the result i get is
**Could not initialize capturing..**

ans =

```
 0
```

Why is this happing i am not able to understand.

Comment: One possibility is that in your Linux terminal you have set some environmental variables that are crucial for the software, but are not available via the MATLAB system command.

Comment: if i run path in terminal i get                                                           /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/shashank/program/matlab/bin:                            In matlab i get (using !echo $PATH)                                                 /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/shashank/program/matlab/bin:

Comment: Check your current path prior to running the command (`pwd`). It could be that MATLAB changes directories relative to where you think you are

Comment: both path was same .i checked it. Other wise the error couldn't be Could not initialize capturing...

Comment: Is it possible to break that command into separate `system` calls to see if one part in particular is causing the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I get same error and solved this problem by adding OpenCV include and library path before my command.
For example, in my case I did as follows:

```
system('PATH=/usr/include/opencv2/:$PATH LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH /misc/lmbraid17/zolfagha/optical_flow/twinFlow /misc/lmbraid17/zolfagha/UCF50/BaseballPitch/v_BaseballPitch_g08_c07.avi -f 1 ...')
```

Best,